# Is there any way to play two youtube videos in one screen at the same time?

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have an activity and want to embed there two youtube players and allow user to play both at the same time.

I need this functionality to allow user to compare two videos.

But, I can't achieve this. When i press on play button in one video, the second video is stopped.

I already tried to use Activity with two youtube fragments in layout, activity with two youtube players in layout, activity with two webviews in layout where i use youtube iFrame, but all time I have the same result - only one playing video.

Also, I found that youtube api have limitation to one video. Any workaround to play two video on one screen at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot run more than one instance of the YouTube view

https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/inline-youtube-view. This is a suite of utility libraries around using YouTube inside your Android, iOS or React Native app.

It has support to play multiple inline youtube videos in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

try to create 2 fragments at the same activity and use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment  ?
Note : i didnt test this but it may work .

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this way and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is a website called youtubedoubler.com providing you have the URLs you can watch 2 videos at once.

Answer (score 0):

Using this library ([Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player)) it should be fairly simple to play multiple YouTube videos at the same time. Just add more YouTubePlayerView to your Activity/Fragment.

Add two YouTubePlayerView to your layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.youtubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.youtubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in your Activity repeat this code for both YouTubePlayerViews:

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view1);

youTubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitSuccess(final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {    
        initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                String videoId = "6JYIGclVQdw";
                initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        });        
    }
}, true);
```

You should be able to do this with as many YouTubePlayerView as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added Android-YouTube-Player library to my project and use your code below. Maybe i do something wrong, but when i press on play button on one player,the second is pausing.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the OS is automatically pausing them. Try placing them inside 2 different Fragments.

Comment: Already tried and achieve the same result. Tested on two devices: Meizu U10 (Android 6.0) and some Lg phone (Android 5.0.2)